# How to pass values multiple levels down

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to build a simple filtering tool that passes values from one to other elements.

I've added a click event to the top level **div1 > input** and trying to get the value of the clicked item and add it to the beginning of all **value** attributes in **div2**.

The problem here is when I select a different subject it keeps the old subject value and adds the new subject aswell.

Can someone please help me with how to make it work so that it only adds the clicked subject's value to the **option values** in **div2**?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var subjects = document.querySelectorAll(".div1 form input");
var yearLvls = document.querySelectorAll(".div2 select option");


subjects.forEach(subject => {
  subject.addEventListener("click", e => {
    var subjectValue = e.target.value;

    yearLvls.forEach(yrLvl => {
      yrLvl.value = subjectValue + yrLvl.value
      console.log(yrLvl.value)
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="div1">

    <input type="radio" value="English" id="English" name="subjects">
    <label for="English">English</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Mathematics" id="Mathematics" name="subjects">
    <label for="Mathematics">Mathematics</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Science" id="Science" name="subjects">
    <label for="Science">Science</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="HASS" id="HASS" name="subjects" />
    <label for="HASS">Humanities and Social Sciences</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="The_Arts" id="The_Arts" name="subjects" />
    <label for="The_Arts">The Arts</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Technologies" id="Technologies" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Technologies">Technologies</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="HPE" id="HPE" name="subjects" />
    <label for="HPE">Health and Physical Education</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Languages" id="Languages" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Languages">Languages</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Work_Studies" id="Work_Studies" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Work_Studies">Work Studies</label>

  </div>


  <div class="div2">
    <select name="year_level">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="Yr-1">Year 1</option>
      <option value="Yr-2">Year 2</option>
      <option value="Yr-3">Year 3</option>
      <option value="Yr-4">Year 4</option>
      <option value="Yr-5">Year 5</option>
      <option value="Yr-6">Year 6</option>
      <option value="Yr-7">Year 7</option>
      <option value="Yr-8">Year 8</option>
      <option value="Yr-9">Year 9</option>
      <option value="Yr-10">Year 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: please create a work snippet. because if i run your code nothing work :)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thats because the `querySelectorAll(".div1 form input")` is incorrect in the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an item to each `option`'s [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to save the original value and reference that when assigning the new value.

Here's an example:

```js
// Get elements
var subjects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".div1 input"));
var yearLvls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".div2 select option"));

// Save the values to the dataset
yearLvls.forEach((yearLvl) => {
  yearLvl.dataset.defaultValue = yearLvl.value;
});

// Add on click listeners
subjects.forEach((subject) => {
  subject.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var subjectValue = e.target.value;

    yearLvls.forEach((yrLvl) => {
      yrLvl.value = subjectValue + yrLvl.dataset.defaultValue;
      console.log(yrLvl.value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
      <div class="div1">
        <input type="radio" value="English" id="English" name="subjects" />
        <label for="English">English</label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          value="Mathematics"
          id="Mathematics"
          name="subjects"
        />
        <label for="Mathematics">Mathematics</label>

        <input type="radio" value="Science" id="Science" name="subjects" />
        <label for="Science">Science</label>

        <input type="radio" value="HASS" id="HASS" name="subjects" />
        <label for="HASS">Humanities and Social Sciences</label>

        <input type="radio" value="The_Arts" id="The_Arts" name="subjects" />
        <label for="The_Arts">The Arts</label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          value="Technologies"
          id="Technologies"
          name="subjects"
        />
        <label for="Technologies">Technologies</label>

        <input type="radio" value="HPE" id="HPE" name="subjects" />
        <label for="HPE">Health and Physical Education</label>

        <input type="radio" value="Languages" id="Languages" name="subjects" />
        <label for="Languages">Languages</label>

        <input
          type="radio"
          value="Work_Studies"
          id="Work_Studies"
          name="subjects"
        />
        <label for="Work_Studies">Work Studies</label>
      </div>

      <div class="div2">
        <select name="year_level">
          <option value=" "> </option>
          <option value="Yr-1">Year 1</option>
          <option value="Yr-2">Year 2</option>
          <option value="Yr-3">Year 3</option>
          <option value="Yr-4">Year 4</option>
          <option value="Yr-5">Year 5</option>
          <option value="Yr-6">Year 6</option>
          <option value="Yr-7">Year 7</option>
          <option value="Yr-8">Year 8</option>
          <option value="Yr-9">Year 9</option>
          <option value="Yr-10">Year 10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Note: I had to change the `subjects` query selector as the one posted was not correct for the example.

Answer (score 1):

putting an event listener to each one of the elements is a little bit inefficient. What you could do instead is add an event listener to the div parent element that contains all your inputs and look for the event.target.closest that will satisfy the element selected and take the value that you need and store it in a context variable. From there you can do as you please with the value. try this little snippet and see if it solves what you´re trying to do. I left a console.log there so you can see on the console what the code is doing.

```js
document.querySelector(".div1").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    const inputSelected = (e.target.closest("input") || {}).value
        document.querySelectorAll("option").forEach( option => {
        if(inputSelected) option.value = inputSelected + option.innerHTML
        console.log(option)
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        
        <div class="div1">
            
            <input type="radio" value="English" id="English" name="subjects">
            <label for="English">English</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="Mathematics" id="Mathematics" name="subjects">
            <label for="Mathematics">Mathematics</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="Science" id="Science" name="subjects">
            <label for="Science">Science</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="HASS" id="HASS" name="subjects" />
            <label for="HASS">Humanities and Social Sciences</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="The_Arts" id="The_Arts" name="subjects" />
            <label for="The_Arts">The Arts</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="Technologies" id="Technologies" name="subjects" />
            <label for="Technologies">Technologies</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="HPE" id="HPE" name="subjects" />
            <label for="HPE">Health and Physical Education</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="Languages" id="Languages" name="subjects" />
            <label for="Languages">Languages</label>
            
            <input type="radio" value="Work_Studies" id="Work_Studies" name="subjects" />
            <label for="Work_Studies">Work Studies</label>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="div2">
            <select name="year_level">
                <option value=" "> </option>
                <option value="Yr-1">Year 1</option>
                <option value="Yr-2">Year 2</option>
                <option value="Yr-3">Year 3</option>
                <option value="Yr-4">Year 4</option>
                <option value="Yr-5">Year 5</option>
                <option value="Yr-6">Year 6</option>
                <option value="Yr-7">Year 7</option>
                <option value="Yr-8">Year 8</option>
                <option value="Yr-9">Year 9</option>
                <option value="Yr-10">Year 10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        
    </form>
    
    
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on("change", "input[name='subjects']", function(e){
    $("#subject_name").html( $(this).val() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <div class="div1">

    <input type="radio" value="English" id="English" name="subjects">
    <label for="English">English</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Mathematics" id="Mathematics" name="subjects">
    <label for="Mathematics">Mathematics</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Science" id="Science" name="subjects">
    <label for="Science">Science</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="HASS" id="HASS" name="subjects" />
    <label for="HASS">Humanities and Social Sciences</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="The_Arts" id="The_Arts" name="subjects" />
    <label for="The_Arts">The Arts</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Technologies" id="Technologies" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Technologies">Technologies</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="HPE" id="HPE" name="subjects" />
    <label for="HPE">Health and Physical Education</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Languages" id="Languages" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Languages">Languages</label>
    
    <input type="radio" value="Work_Studies" id="Work_Studies" name="subjects" />
    <label for="Work_Studies">Work Studies</label>

  </div>


  <div class="div2">
    <select name="year_level">
      <option value="" selected disabled id="subject_name">Please Select Subject</option>
      <option value="Yr-1">Year 1</option>
      <option value="Yr-2">Year 2</option>
      <option value="Yr-3">Year 3</option>
      <option value="Yr-4">Year 4</option>
      <option value="Yr-5">Year 5</option>
      <option value="Yr-6">Year 6</option>
      <option value="Yr-7">Year 7</option>
      <option value="Yr-8">Year 8</option>
      <option value="Yr-9">Year 9</option>
      <option value="Yr-10">Year 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>


</form>
```

> References: [.change() JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/change/)